# How to stop existing dispatchqueue and start new?

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-queue

```
    @objc func textFieldChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
            self.shouldEnableBtn()
        })
}
```

Here, If I enter textFieldChanged again, I want to cancel existing dispatchque and start new.

Comment: You could try `DispatchWorkItem` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DispatchWorkItem` class which allows you to cancel your task individually.

```
    let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
        self.shouldEnableBtn()
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: workItem)

    // To cancel the work-item task
    workItem.cancel()
```

Better you can use the `OperationQueue` for this task as following:

```
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
    operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

    // Add operation in the queue
    operationQueue.addOperation {
        self.shouldEnableBtn()
    }

    // Cancel to on-going operation by
    operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()

    // Pause to on-going operation by
    operationQueue.isSuspended = true
```

Comment: Thanks , I cant use operation queue as it contains UI.  for the first example i need to cancel existing first then wanted to create new.